# Application of '/' in some header files

Tags: c++, c, include, header-files

Recently I have come across a couple of header files like

```
 #include <sys/socket.h>
 #include <sys/types.h>
 #include <netinet/in.h>
 #include <bits/stdc++.h>
```

I wanted to know the actual reason as to why **'/'** is used.

So far I have taken it as an operation to include the sub-header file of a bigger header file just like Java

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
```

but
If you remove the '/' and try to include the header file as whole
It shows an error that header file doesn't exists.

Kindly clear the confusion regarding this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: On second thought that dupe might not be what you are asking.  linking it here though.  related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5790161/is-the-backslash-acceptable-in-c-and-c-include-directives

Comment: By the way: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/560648

Answer (score 4):

Directory separation. For example, there is a directory `sys` which has a header file called `socket.h`.

And as paths in the filesystem, it can be multiple levels. You can have `#include <some/sub/directory/with/a/file.h>`.

The actually use of slash (`/`) versus backslash (`\`) (or anything else really) is not standardized, but is depending on the system. However all major platforms support slash (`/`) as separators in paths so it's most common.

Comment: I see , so the first word represented the directory. thank you very much.

Comment: Note that strictly speaking, the C++ standard says nothing on how these strings are handled. It just so happens that (nearly?) all compilers currently in use, interpret them as filenames including directories.

Comment: @Ryuzaki As rubenvb commented, it doesn't really have to be directories. It just makes sense that it is, and that the whole "path" is part of an actual path in a filesystem.

Answer (score 3):

Files on your hard drive are organised into *directories* (or "folders").

The full name of a file is identified by its path, which may name several of these directories, separated by a slash character (`/`) or a backslash character (`\`).

Read more here:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_(computing)
- https://support.dtsearch.com/webhelp/dtsearch/relative_paths.htm

Comment: The backslash character works only on MS Windows AFAIK, while slash works in whole *NIX world plus the windows support it too. So for source portability reasons I would stay with slash only.

Comment: @Ped7g: As would I. I am simply explaining what directories are, since the OP doesn't seem to know.

Answer (score 1):

When you build a c++ file, the preprocessor looks for the files you specified to include in a set of directories (default ones + directories you pass on the command line).

For each `#include <something>` it tries to open `BASE_DIR/something` where `BASE_DIR` is one of the aforementioned directories.

So `sys/socket.h` denoted the preprocessor should try and delve into the subdirectory `sys` and open `socket.h`