# g++ include directory in the headerfile

Tags: c++, include, g++

The path to my .cpp and .h files: `/home/quasiturbine/ServerProject/Network/NetworkIncludes/`

There you can find `TCP_Connexion.h` and `TCP_Connexion.cpp`

In the .cpp file, I got `#include "NetworkIncludes\TCP_Connexion.h"` and default constructor/destructor. That's it.

G++ command:

```
g++ -o program -I/home/quasiturbine/ServerProject/Network/ /home/quasiturbine/ServerProject/Network/NetworkIncludes/TCP_Connexion.cpp
```

> fatal error:
>       /home/quasiturbine/ServerProject/Network/NetworkIncludes/TCP_Connexion.cpp:1:43: fatal error: NetworkIncludes\TCP_Connexion.h: No such file or folder
>       #include "NetworkIncludes\TCP_Connexion.h"

What is wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: I think you want to add you Project Folder as include Directory. With gcc/g++ you Need to add the following flag: `-I/home/quasiturbine/ServerProject/Network/`

Comment: My I look like an L but it's an i

Comment: try to use `#include <NetworkIncludes\TCP_Connexion.h>` instead of `#include "NetworkIncludes\TCP_Connexion.h"`

Comment: I dont know if I was clear...after program, it's in Include, not a link

Comment: I tried with brackets <> and coma ""

Comment: by the way how did you make that capital i? If I do a capital i, it looks like this : I,   i = I  no bars on top and bottom...  maybe it's the issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is, that you are using backslashes `\` when you should be using forward slashes `/`. Backslashes in include paths are undefined behavior before `C++11` and implementation defined afterwards ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5790161)).

So change your include to

```
#include "NetworkIncludes/TCP_Connexion.h"
```

and you should be good to go.